# Valgrind stack trace missing symbol names

Tags: valgrind, stack-trace, symbols

I am running "valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full -v" and the call stack being reported is missing symbols. Here's what I'm seeing:

```
==11734== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 29
==11734==    at 0x4005903: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==11734==    by 0x5308223: ???
==11734==    by 0x53077FB: ???
==11734==    by 0x52D8B17: ???
==11734==    by 0x52F3A1D: ???
==11734==    by 0x5259B3D: ???
==11734==    by 0x5258274: ???
==11734==    by 0x5251E26: ???
==11734==    by 0x524735D: ???
```

I am running a debug build using shared object libs, but this should not be a problem because I have used valgrind on this app many times, using shared object libs. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you compile with debug symbol?

Comment: Are you using shared libraries that are loaded with `dlopen` and then unloaded with `dlclose` before the program exits?

Comment: @TomH no, we not using dlopen/dlclose